# MySQL Count presence of multiple values in same column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a single table called Customers with a CustID column and another column called ProductCode. There are 33 possible products (numbered 1 to 33) and each customer can have any combination of products. There is a single row for each customer and all of the products that each customer has are shown in the ProductCode column with a space in between i.e:

```
CUSTID     PRODUCTCODE  
------     -----------

001        3 12 18 22 32  
002        9 6 18 36  
003        3 6 7 26  
004        9 11 33   
005        6 21 28 29 30 31  
006        1 3 6 21 30 31
```

I need to be able to do a count of each product and add a text description of the code:

```
ProdCode    Description       Count  
~~~~~~~~    ~~~~~~~~~~~       ~~~~~  
1           Lawnmower         1  
3           Spade             3  
6           Clippers          4  
etc
```

Thanks!

Comment: Put customer ID in one column and product codes one per row and you'll be able to perform any kind of grouping and counting as you wish. Your way is not SQLish so to speak.:

Answer (score 0):

### Never, never, never store multiple values in one column!

As you see now this will only result in problems. Please normalize your DB structure with an additional table

```
customer_products
CUSTID     PRODUCTCODE  
------     -----------
001        3
001        12
001        18
---
002        9
002        6
...
```

Then you can remove the `PRODUCTCODE` column from your `customer` table.

Comment: I'm having to work with what I've got. No option to restructure - hence the question.

Answer (score 0):

One solution can be to change you schema to have two columns:-

1) Customer Id
2) Product Id

So data would look something like this:-

```
cust_id| product_id

001    | 3
001    | 6
002    | 9
```

...
...

So now in mysql query you can use query like

```
Select product_id,count(*) as num_products from table_name group by product_id;
```

Hope this helps.

If you cant alter your schema, then you have to fetch the data and in your scripting language you have to process it as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE ord (custid VARCHAR(3), productcode VARCHAR(40));

INSERT INTO ord VALUES ('001', '3 12 18 22 32');
INSERT INTO ord VALUES ('002', '9 6 18 36');
INSERT INTO ord VALUES ('003', '3 6 7 26');
INSERT INTO ord VALUES ('004', '9 11 33');
INSERT INTO ord VALUES ('005', '6 21 28 29 30 31');
INSERT INTO ord VALUES ('006', '1 3 6 21 30 31');

CREATE TABLE products (code VARCHAR(2));

INSERT INTO products VALUES ('3');
INSERT INTO products VALUES ('12');
INSERT INTO products VALUES ('18');
INSERT INTO products VALUES ('22');
INSERT INTO products VALUES ('32');
INSERT INTO products VALUES ('9');
INSERT INTO products VALUES ('6');
INSERT INTO products VALUES ('31');

CREATE TABLE ord_prod (code VARCHAR(2), count_of_products INT) AS
  SELECT p.code, 
        (SELECT COUNT(1)
           FROM ord o
         WHERE INSTR(CONCAT(' ', o.productcode, ' '), CONCAT(' ', p.code, ' ')) > 0) AS count_of_products
    FROM products p;
```

Check at SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a7f94/1

Change your types as you need, add the rest of the products, add the description etc.